# How to Install SpagoBI application In ubuntu

Tags: tomcat7, spagobi

I am getting the following error.

> HTTP Status 404 - /SpagoBIBirtReportEngine/BirtReportServlet type
>   Status report message /SpagoBIBirtReportEngine/BirtReportServlet
>   description The requested resource is not available.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: From the error is that the application is not getting the resource. What kind of application it is ?

Comment: It may not be able to isolate the specific problem without more information. What version of SpagoBI are you using? Are you using the All In One installation?  Is the SpagoBIBirtReportEngine app/folder in the Tomcat webapps folder? What is the full URL you are using to access SpagoBI?

Comment: I am using 5.2 version.I installed it manually.I downloaded .war file and I placed the same in tomcat folder.There SpagoBI folder exists and not the SpagoBI Studio.http://localhost:8080/SpagoBI/servlet/AdapterHTTP?PAGE=LoginPage&NEW_SESSION=TRUE

Comment: Can you please share me the complete documentation to install SpagoBI in ubuntu?

Comment: You can get the complete application of SpagoBI through the official website. the all in one package is available there which consists of both SpagoBIstudio and server.